# Error during sync: UpdateURLMap: googleapi: Error 413: Value for field resource.pathMatchers[0].pathRules is too large

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

When I add morethan 50 Paths in the Ingress file - getting below error from Google Cloud Platform.

**"Error during sync: UpdateURLMap: googleapi: Error 413: Value for field 'resource.pathMatchers[0].pathRules' is too large: maximum size 50 element(s); actual size 51., fieldSizeTooLarge"**

We are using Path based Ingress thru Traefik. This error coming from Google Cloud Platform.

Sample Ingress looklike:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain-name.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: default-http-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: foo1-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /foo1/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: foo2-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /foo2/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: foo3-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /foo3/*
```

Comment: I just run into the same issue. Have you found a valid workaround? it would be great if "path" could be specified as a comma separated list, all of them with the same backend, that will save some mappings.

Comment: we can't. Only workaround is create another ingress controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your ingress is using a layer 7 load balancer in GCP and the limit for path rules is 50. I couldn't find a standard limit for the path rules in an HTTP(s) load balancer in GCP in their docs. You can see it host and path rules for your LB:

[image: host and path rules]

I recommend:

1. Create another ingress controller.
2. Open a support ticket with GCP so that they can increase the limit on path rules for your HTTP(s) load balancer for your project if they can.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard limitation of the URLMap resource, [which cannot be increased](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas).

> URL maps
>
> Host rules per URL map - 50 - This limit cannot be increased.

Here's a feature request to increase this limit: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126946582

Comment: What is the solution if I need to support many more URLs?

Comment: More context https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/15v0hbz/global_external_application_load_balancer_url_map/